# Is there a visual bash pipeline editor

Tags: bash, pipeline

I have plenty of bash scripts with various files being piped into various scripts and it does my head in a bit.

I wondered if there was a way of visualising the pipeline in a bash script so I can easily see the flow.

Comment: I can't think of anything other than adding `set -x` to the script.

Comment: What visualization other than `producer | filter | consumer` do you have in mind?

Comment: yes, or taking apart the pipelines in parts, (maybe adding `head` or `tail -10` to limit output. With tripleee's example, i.e. `producer  | head -10`, then `producer | filter | head -10`, etc etc. Good luck.

Comment: I'm having horrible thoughts of abusing `set -x` or `set -v` and filtered output from `strace`/etc. to string something together but that's going to be a fair bit of work I think.

Comment: @shellter Well, that one `head -n 10` is one example of a `filter`.  Maybe the OP would like to understand the actual commands in the pipeline, rather than actually understand the pipes as such, though?

Comment: @tripleee : that's just my interpretation of what O.P. is looking for. IHMO the specification of "visualising the pipeline" has a lot of latitude. Note the 2 widely divergent full answers below ;-) ! Good luck to all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add newlines after the pipe, and bash will continue to see it as a single pipeline:

```
foo | bar | baz | qux
```

can be written as

```
foo |
bar |
baz |
qux
```

Or, use line continuations, if the look appeals more:

```
foo \
| bar \
| baz \
| qux
```

Newlines are acceptable after `|`, `&&` and `||`

Answer (score 3):

Try [pv](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml). It shows you how much data is being transferred in the pipe. Example usage (I got this image from the website):
[image: pv example]

`pv` prints its progress bars to stderr. In your case, you could use:

```
foo | pv -cN foo |
bar | pv -cN bar |
baz | pv -cN baz |
qux | pv -cN qux
```